# leave specific file out of pkg executable (node.js - restify - pkg)

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a project which is compiled in one executable file (with https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). But one file in the root directory is a config file, to set up the database string. Do you know how I can leave this specific file out of the executable file?

Thanks for your help!